# Update Date object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I've been doing a page and one of my current requirements it's for it to run with the server's time instead of the client's local time that is used by the Date object, my first approach was to require the time from the server each second but this is really inefficient, so I was wondering, is there any way to, after requesting the Date object from the server once, update the same Date object each second to continue with the one it got from the server?

Comment: `setInterval` can be your friend.

Comment: It's true that `setInterval()` will allow you to update a local Date object, but it will still be using the client clock.

Comment: You have problem with timezone? If  yes use utc in both the client and the server.

Comment: You only need to calculate an offset once (using a value from the server) then adjust the local time by that amount whenever you need it.

Comment: @AlexK. I dont know if this is a good idea because in some countries use (DST) so this can be problematic. 
I think that if he will use UTC in the server and client it always be the same.

Comment: It wouldn't work to just calculate the offset, cause let's say the client changes his date/time once the original time has already been requested then the offset would be wrong and it'd display the wrong date.

Comment: @BaekRyun—yes of course, you can't avoid that. But you might only check with the server every 5 or 10 minutes instead of every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: (this is an implementation for angularjs)
the thing is a Date object has a function called getTime() which returns the # of millisenconds that has passed since 1970 so you can just use that number and keep adding 1000 milliseconds each second that way you dont have to rely on multiple requests nor in the local time

```
$scope.current_TimeStamp = 0;
 $scope.clock= function(){

    setTimeout($scope.clock, 1000);
    $scope.current_TimeStamp+=1000;
    var today = new Date($scope.current_TimeStamp)
    var days = [ 'Domingo','Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
    var months = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
    var date = days[today.getDay()] +" " + today.getDate()+ " de " + months[today.getMonth()] + " "+ today.toLocaleTimeString() ;

    if(document.getElementById('time') !== null)
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = date;
 }
 $scope.startTime= function(){      
   // make the request to get the date from the server
   // in my case I store it in $scope.current_TimeStamp
   RoomService.RequestTime().then(function(response){
      var date = new Date(response.data)
      $scope.current_TimeStamp = date.getTime()
      var t = setTimeout($scope.clock, 1000);
    })

 }
 $scope.startTime();
```

Comment: You're depending on setTimeout to run at *exactly* 1 second intervals, which it will not do. It will always be a bit late, which will cause the clock to slowly drift. There is also no need for *getTime*. To add one second to a date, use `date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1)`.

Comment: Well about depending of setTimeout it might be better to use setInterval it'd be slightly better, if there's another way I'm not aware of it, but this was the first way I thought of doing it so I posted it like that, and thanks for the alternative to getTime, this answer would've saved me about an two hours of wasted time haha, tho I guess time used learning is never wasted.

Comment: Likely the best solution is that by Alex K: send the time from the server and get the difference with the client. Round to the nearest 15 minutes (which is the smallest increment for a time zone) and just apply that offset each time a new date is created to display the time. To keep a clock ticking reasonably accurately, call setTimeout sequentially and make the delay to the next call based on the milliseconds of the current Date plus a value that is about 10 milliseconds after the next full second.